# Custom CursorAdapter in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment that utilizes a Database class that I created. I have a method called populateListView(), which uses a CursorAdapter to fill a ListView with data. My issue is that I keep getting a syntax error stating that the 'CursorAdapter is abstract and cannot be instantiated'. I didn't have any problems when using this code in an Activity but it wont work in a Fragment. Does anybody know why?

Here is the code from my Fragment:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts_fragments, container, false);

    inputName = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputNumber = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.inputNumber);
    inputEmail = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
    saveButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    deleteAllButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.deleteAllButton);
    openDB();
    populateListView();

    return view;
}

private void openDB(){
    myDB = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
    myDB.open();
}

public void populateListView(){
    View view = getView();
    Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllRows();
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] {DBAdapter.KEY_NAME,DBAdapter.KEY_NUMBER,DBAdapter.KEY_EMAIL};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] {R.id.customRowContactName,R.id.customRowContactNumber,R.id.customRowRowEmail};

    CursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
    //***SYNTAX ERROR WITH FOLLOWING LINE***
    cursorAdapter = new CursorAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.contacts_custom_row,cursor,fromFieldNames,toViewIDs);

    myList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CursorAdapter` is an abstract class which means it cannot be instantiated.

In your activity you are probably using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` since your constructor arguments match what it requires or you might be using your own implementation of a `CursorAdapter`.

Either of these will work in a `Fragment` if it already works in an `Activity` you are using.

```
cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.contacts_custom_row,
                                        cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs);
```

Comment: Yes, so SimpleCursorAdapter does indeed work but Android is telling me that it's deprecated.... SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.contacts_custom_row,cursor,fromFieldNames,toViewIDs);....Do you know what should be used instead?

Comment: Yes. The documentation for the method actually mentions why you should no longer use it and what to use instead http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter(android.content.Context, int, android.database.Cursor, java.lang.String[], int[])). Basically to use the `LoaderManager` with a `CursorLoader` to make sure the query is performed off the UI thread and any queries after an update are done off the UI thread too.

Comment: If you are already loading the data off the UI thread there is another overloaded constructor that takes flags. If you don't want it to automatically requery when the data is updated you can use that instead. `cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.contacts_custom_row,
                                        cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs, 0);`

Comment: Last quick thing, so what am I placing in the last parameter within the constructor where the int array is?

Comment: The `int[]` parameter is an array of view ids from the layout file you are using. It is an associative array to the `String[]`. Each String maps to a column in the cursor and its value will be populated into the view with the id in the `int[]`.